# What is the best way to do periodical cleanups inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, cron, uwsgi

I have a docker container that runs a simple custom download server using `uwsgi` on debian and a python script. The files are generated and saved inside the container for each request. Now, periodically I want to delete old files that the server generated for past requests.

So far, I achieved the cleanup via a cronjob **on the host**, that looks something like this:

```
*/30 * * * *   docker exec mycontainer /path/on/container/delete_old_files.sh
```

But that has a few drawbacks:

- Cron needs to be installed and running on the docker host
- The user manually has to add a cronjob for each container they start
- There is an extra cleanup script in the source
- The fact that the cron job is needed needs to be documented

I would much prefer a solution that rolls out with the docker container and is also suitable for more general periodical tasks in the background of a docker container.

Any best practices on this?

Does python or uwsgi have an easy mechanism for periodical background tasks?

I'm aware, that I could install cron inside the container and to something like: `CMD ['sh', '-c', 'cron; uswgi <uswgi-options>... --wsgi-file server.py']` but that seems a bit clonky and against docker philosopy.

A solution like this in `server.py`:

```
def cleanup():
    # ...
    threading.Timer(30*60, cleanup).start() # seconds...

cleanup()

# ... rest of the code here ...
```

Seems good, but I'm not sure how it interferes with `uwsgi`'s own threading and processing.

It seems like a simple problem but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* store live data in containers.  Containers can be a little bit fragile and need to be deleted and restarted routinely (because you forgot an option; because the underlying image has a critical security fix) and when this happens you will lose all of the data that's in the container.

What you can do instead is use a `docker run -v` option to cause the data to be stored in a path on the host.  If they're all in the same place then you can have one cron job that cleans them all up.  Running cron on the host is probably the right solution here, though in principle you could have a separate dedicated cron container that did the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks david, in my case, the data is just cached for a relatively short duration, and I don't care if it gets lost on container deletion. It's more debugging and short-term storage for performance.